# Получить полный путь до элемента, в иерархической таблице MS SQL (с использованием hierarchyid)

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, hierarchy

Имеется вот такая иерархическая структура данных:

```
1 Проект
  2 Этап
    3 Документация
      4 Чертёж
```

Здесь номер означает (условно говоря) поле hierarchyid, а название поле name в таблице. В MS SQL определён метод ToString(), который позволяет получить например для последнего элемента (следующее:

```
4.ToString()

/1/2/3/4/
```

Но такой вариант мне не подходит, я бы хотел получить вот такой результат:

```
/Проект/Этап/Документация/Чертёж/
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить такой полный путь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть есть данные

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (path hierarchyid, name nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES
    ('/1/', N'AA'),
    ('/1/1/', N'BBB'),
    ('/1/1/1/', N'CCCC'),
    ('/1/1/1/1/', N'DDDDD');
```

и переменная, содержащая путь интересующего узла

```
DECLARE @node hierarchyid = '/1/1/1/1/';
```

тогда в SqlServer 2017 (и старше) можно соединить имена узлов так:

```
SELECT
    '/' + STRING_AGG(d.name, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l.level DESC) + '/'
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) l(level)
    JOIN @data d ON d.path = @node.GetAncestor(level)
```

для более ранних версий, например, так:

```
SELECT
    '/' + (
        SELECT
            d.name + '/'
        FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) l(level)
            JOIN @data d ON d.path = @node.GetAncestor(level)
        ORDER BY l.level DESC
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Если уровней больше, чем четыре, то в `(VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) l(level)` нужно добавить констант.

Если число уровней заранее неизвестно, то вместо набора чисел можно использовать числогенерирующую функцию, например *GetNumsRange* от Itzik Ben-Gan ([здесь](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/use-t-sql-generate-sequence)). Также потребуется дополнительная переменная для глубины узла

```
DECLARE @level int = @node.GetLevel();
```

соответственно в запросе вместо

```
(VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3)) l(level)
```

нужно будет подставить

```
(SELECT n FROM dbo.GetNumsRange(0, @level - 1)) l(level)
```

Comment: А если у меня не ограниченное кол-во уровней (файловая система) ?

Comment: @ИванК, дополнил ответ. Надеюсь у вас там не FileTable, т.к. для FileTable всё решается гораздо проще.

Comment: а как решается для FileTable? Просто я пока не знаю как лучше сделать?

Comment: @ИванК, для FileTable есть специальная функция [GetFileNamespacePath](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/getfilenamespacepath-transact-sql), т.е. тогда будет, например, `SELECT file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath() FROM [FileTableName] WHERE path_locator = @node`